# How Can I Determine the Drive Letter for the Drive My Script is Currently Running On?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I will need to find a way of knowing what drive my usb is on, so I could copy some files from the PC on to the flash drive. I already know how to do this using powershell, however I need a way of doing it via .bat and cmd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to do it via batch? Just get batch to call your PowerShell script, then you're not over complicating the code.

Comment: When you don't want a [tag:PowerShell] solution, why do you put that tag? Anyway, your question is too broad for this site, unless you show what you have tried so far and describe the specific error you are facing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your running script is always, `%0` and the drive letter holding your running script can be referenced using variable modifiers.

From `Call/?`

```
%~d1 - expands %1 to a drive letter only
```

Example:

```
Echo %~d0
```

Comment: SS64 has a good reference for these modifiers. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html